# In Eclipse, how to bind Control-N to "down", like arrow key, any window?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I have Control-N and Control-P bound to the "Line Down" and "Line Up" commands, so when I'm editing text, I can move up and down without moving my hands away from typing position.  But it annoys me that many of the other dialogs, or little popups, require that I use the mouse or arrow keys.  For example, when I run "Quick Switch Editor" (Command-E) or "Open Resource" (Command-Shift-R), I get lists of files in a popup.  Is there a command to bind, or some other way, to use Control-N, Control-P to move the selected item up and down in these lists.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like what you want to do goes beyond the standard eclipse out of the box capabilities. 
how about going one step up the food chain and have the OS do the key mapping for you?

assuming  your running windows, give **[SharpKeys](http://www.randyrants.com/sharpkeys/)** a try

and here is a short  **[sharp keys how to at how to geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/)**

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this idea, but I use a Mac.

Comment: maybe you can record a macro using http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/ or something similar. 
also there is [blog post](http://heisencoder.net/2008/04/fixing-up-mac-key-bindings-for-windows.html) about key mapping in mac